# Opening a file through child process in nodeJs is waiting for the file close to end the execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, command-prompt

I am opening a file through child process in nodeJs, which is working fine, but is waiting for the opened file to close to end the execution. I am new to javascript and nodeJs just wanted to know Is there any way to just open the file and continue to complete the execution and not just keep waiting until someone closes the file

The sample code I tried:

```
const { exec } = require('node:child_process')
exec('C:\\Logs\\log_2-46-28-pm.txt', (err, output) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("could not execute command: ", err)
        return
    }else{
    console.log("Output: \n", output)
    }
});
```

I also tried other command to open the file like choosing a particular app to open but it gave same result:

```
"start %windir%\\system32\\notepad.exe C:\\Logs\\log_2-46-28-pm.txt"
```

For opening folder I tried the command:

```
'start %windir%\\explorer.exe "C:\\Logs\\"'
```

which works fine and not wait for th file explorer window to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this.

You make spawn to work with async/await.

In your case, there is a pending callback to be executed. The script will not finish before it runs.

````js
const { spawn: spwn } = require('child_process')

/**
 * This is a spawn wrapper to make it use async/await syntax
 */
const spawn = (
  cmd,
  args,
  opts,
) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const cp = spwn(cmd, args, opts);
  const error = [];
  const stdout = [];
  cp.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    stdout.push(data.toString());
  });

  cp.on('error', (e) => {
    error.push(e.toString());
  });

  cp.on('close', () => {
    if (error.length) reject(error.join(''));
    else resolve(stdout.join(''));
  });
});


/**
 * This is just an immediately called
 * function opening your file and following the execution
 */
(async () => {
  try {
    //Just change the file path inside the argument list HERE
    const stdOut = await spawn('powershell.exe', [`${__dirname}/test.txt`]);
    console.log('stdOut: ', stdOut);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error:', error);
  }
  console.log('continued execution');
})()```
````